# how do I update my Google Apps Marketplace SDK project's Terms of Service URL?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have started the process of publishing a Google Docs add-on in the Google Apps Marketplace. I filled out the project's configuration module in the Developer's Console. Now I would like to update some of the project's configuration information, for example the Terms of Service URL. Since I didn't have an actual Terms of Service document when I started the process, I just put in a base domain. Now I would like to point directly to the document itself (which is hosted on the same domain), but when I "Save Changes", the Terms of Service URL just won't update. The first base domain URL I put in for the Terms of Service URL the first time round stays exactly as is, and doesn't update to the direct URL to the document. Is this a bug in the configuration module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the configuration screen. Please file a bug here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?labels=Type-Defect,API-Marketplace